# Get date diff then add 1 to each month in between

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

What we're attempting to do is to get an accurate representation of the typical volume of orders in a month.
Every following month (including the month the order was open) will have a count of 1 for that order until it was closed. 
So for e.g. 2 orders were created in Feb 2017, thus February will have a count of 2. For order no. 4, every month following June will have a count of 1 for that particular order.

```
WAREHOUSENO ORDERNO ORDER DATE  CLOSED DATE
1           ABC     2/22/17      3/10/17
2           DEF     2/23/17      4/1/17
1           GHI     3/1/17       3/28/17
3           JKL     6/1/17  
2           MNO     9/1/17       10/12/17
3           PQR     10/22/17     2/23/18
1           STU     12/5/17      12/28/17
2           VWX     2/8/18  
3           YZ      3/15/18
```

At the end we would like to sum all of the counts for each month, grouped by warehouse & year.

```
     Month                                          
     WAREHOUSE    Jan   Feb   Mar  Apr  May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
         1          0    1     1     0   0    0  0   0   0   0   0   1
2017     2          0    1     1     0   0    0  0   0   1   1   0   0
         3          0    0     0     0   0    1  1   1   1   2   2   2
TOTAL OPEN               2     2              1  1   1   2   3   2   3

         1          0     0    0     0                          
2018     2          1     1    1     1    
         3          1     1    2     2    
TOTAL OPEN          2     1    3     3
```

Would really appreciate some direction with this!

Comment: In my opinion, your question is too broad because the desired output is a kind of report and sql-server can serve queries but not reports.

Comment: Please edit your post to narrow it down to a specific question for which TSQL is sufficient/appropriate. You can use `pivot` _et al._ to get the counts you want, but it wouldn't be a good idea to try to do the final presentation in SSMS; rather, you should use a reporting frontend for that.

Comment: There are many challenges here to say the least. Why does your output start with Jan 2017? You have no data for that month. Why does it end at April 2018? Again....no data for that month. You are going to need a tally table or a calendar table to do this because you want data returned outside the data available. Returning the data isn't a huge deal, but the formatting belongs at the presentation layer, not the database. Here is a good place to start.http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am new to posting questions here regarding T-SQL so those directions really help for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after a count of the open order in each warehouse each month?  If so I believe the code below will do what you're after:

```
declare @sampleData table
(
    warehouseNo int not null
    ,orderNo nvarchar(5) not null
    , orderDate DateTime not null
    , closedDate DateTime
)

insert @sampleData (warehouseNo, orderNo, orderDate, closedDate)
values (1 ,'ABC', '2017-02-22', '2017-03-10')
,      (2 ,'DEF', '2017-02-23', '2017-04-01')
,      (1 ,'GHI', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-28')
,      (3 ,'JKL', '2017-06-01', null)
,      (2 ,'MNO', '2017-09-01', '2017-10-12')
,      (3 ,'PQR', '2017-10-22', '2018-02-23')
,      (1 ,'STU', '2017-12-05', '2017-12-28')
,      (2 ,'VWX', '2018-02-08', null)  
,      (3 ,'YZ',  '2018-03-15', null)

declare @start datetime 
, @end datetime

select @start = dateadd(day,1-day(min(orderDate)),min(orderDate))
, @end = max(coalesce(closedDate, getutcdate()))
from @sampleData

;with allDates as 
(
    select @start FirstOfMonth

    union all

    select dateadd(month,1,FirstOfMonth) 
    from allDates
    where FirstOfMonth <= @end
)
, normalisedDates as --round all dates down to first of the month since we only care about month and year; not day
(
    select warehouseNo
    , dateadd(day,1 - datepart(day, orderDate), orderDate) orderDate
    , dateadd(day,1 - datepart(day, coalesce(closedDate, getutcdate())), coalesce(closedDate, getutcdate())) closedDate
    from @sampleData
)
select ad.FirstOfMonth
, nd.warehouseNo 
, count(nd.warehouseNo) OpenOrderCount
from allDates ad
left outer join normalisedDates nd
on ad.FirstOfMonth between nd.orderDate and nd.closedDate
group by ad.FirstOfMonth, nd.warehouseNo
order by ad.FirstOfMonth, nd.warehouseNo
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b3891/1)

---

#### Update

Regarding your question about pivoting by month; sure.

See here for a great article on pivoting: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

See below for code for your scenario:

```
declare @start datetime 
, @end datetime

select @start = dateadd(day,1-day(min(orderDate)),min(orderDate))
, @end = max(coalesce(closedDate, getutcdate()))
from @sampleData

;with allDates as 
(
    select @start FirstOfMonth

    union all

    select dateadd(month,1,FirstOfMonth) 
    from allDates
    where FirstOfMonth <= @end
)
, normalisedDates as --round all dates down to first of the month since we only care about month and year; not day
(
    select warehouseNo
    , dateadd(day,1 - datepart(day, orderDate), orderDate) orderDate
    , dateadd(day,1 - datepart(day, coalesce(closedDate, getutcdate())), coalesce(closedDate, getutcdate())) closedDate
    from @sampleData
)
select warehouseNo, [1] Jan, [2] Feb, [3] Mar, [4] Apr, [5] May, [6] Jun, [7] Jul, [8] Aug, [9] Sep, [10] Oct, [11] Nov, [12] Dec
from 
(
    select datepart(month,ad.FirstOfMonth) MonthX
    , nd.warehouseNo 
    , count(nd.warehouseNo) OpenOrderCount
    from allDates ad
    left outer join normalisedDates nd
    on ad.FirstOfMonth between nd.orderDate and nd.closedDate
    group by ad.FirstOfMonth, nd.warehouseNo
) x
pivot 
(
    sum(OpenOrderCount) for MonthX in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) 
) p
order by warehouseNo
```

Comment: This pretty much gets me to where I need to be. Is there a way to pivot the table with Months as the columns and a count of each open order by warehouse?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table sampleData
(
    warehouseNo int not null
    ,orderNo nvarchar(5) not null
    , orderDate DateTime not null
    , closedDate DateTime
)

insert sampleData (warehouseNo, orderNo, orderDate, closedDate)
values (1 ,'ABC', '2017-02-22', '2017-03-10')
,      (2 ,'DEF', '2017-02-23', '2017-04-01')
,      (1 ,'GHI', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-28')
,      (3 ,'JKL', '2017-06-01', null)
,      (2 ,'MNO', '2017-09-01', '2017-10-12')
,      (3 ,'PQR', '2017-10-22', '2018-02-23')
,      (1 ,'STU', '2017-12-05', '2017-12-28')
,      (2 ,'VWX', '2018-02-08', null)  
,      (3 ,'YZ',  '2018-03-15', null)



SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(5), year(orderDate)), 'Total') AS [YEAR]
        ,ISNULL(warehouseNo, '') AS [Warehouse]
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 1 THEN orderNo END) AS JAN
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 2 THEN orderNo END) AS FEB
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 3 THEN orderNo END) AS MAR
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 4 THEN orderNo END) AS APR
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 5 THEN orderNo END) AS MAY
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 6 THEN orderNo END) AS JUN
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 7 THEN orderNo END) AS JUL
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 8 THEN orderNo END) AS AUG
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 9 THEN orderNo END) AS SEP
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 10 THEN orderNo END) AS OCT
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 11 THEN orderNo END) AS NOV
        ,count(CASE WHEN MONTH(orderDate) = 12 THEN orderNo END) AS DEC
    FROM sampleData
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(year(orderDate), warehouseNo)
        --order by ISNULL(CONVERT(char(5),year(orderDate)),'Total')
```